# sql oracle get all possible values of a lib table

Tags: sql, oracle

I am using sql ORACLE

I have a library table:

```
libid   libdescr
1       boss
2       secretary
3       manager
```

And a table with some info:

```
id  libid   descr
1   1   jim
1   2   james
2   1   rony
2   2   fred
2   3   jana
```

I want to join both, but I have to have all possible values of the library. So my result have to be:

```
id  libid   libdescr    descr
1   1       bos         jim
1   2       secretary   james
1   3       manager     <null>
2   1       boss        rony
2   2       secretary   fred
2   3       manager     jana
```

If I do a join

```
select info.*,lib.libdescr
from info
left join lib
on lib.libid = info.libid
```

I don't get the row `id=1 and libid=3`

How can I make sure I have all the possible values?

Answer (score 1):

In your query either you need to use right join or use the below query :

```
select i.*, l.libdescr from lib l left join info i on l.libid=i.libid;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a `cross join` to generate the rows and a `left join` to bring in the values from the other table:

```
select i.id, l.libid, l.libdescr, s.descr
from (select distinct id from someinfo) i cross join
     library l left join
     someinfo s
     on s.id = i.id and s.libid = l.libid;
```

Comment: When I do that I get a lot of duplicated values. When I add a distinct I get the desired result, but I am not happy to add a distinct.

Comment: @Bigjo . . . The duplicate values would presumably be matches in `someinfo`.  You'll have to figure out what you want when there are duplicate rows there.